# How should Exponential Moving Average be used in custom TF2.4 training loop

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a custom training loop that can be simplified as follow

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 3))
model = tf.keras.Model({"inputs": inputs}, {"loss": f(inputs)})
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

for inputs in batches:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        results = model(inputs, training=True)
    grads = tape.gradient(results["loss"], model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

The [TensorFlow documentation of ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) is not clear on how it should be used in [from-scratch training loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch). As anyone worked with this?

Additionally, how should the shadow variable be restored into the model if both are still in memory, and how can I check that that training variables were correctly updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the EMA object before the training loop:

```
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.9999)
```

And then just apply the EMA after your optimization step. The ema object will keep shadow variables of your model's variables. (You don't need the call to `tf.control_dependencies` here, see the note in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies))

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
ema.apply(model.trainable_variables)
```

Then, one way to use the shadow variables into your model could be to assign to your model's variables the shadow variable by calling the `average` method of the EMA object on them:

```
for var in model.trainable_variables:
    var.assign(ema.average(var))
model.save("model_with_shadow_variables.h5")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I be sure the exponential moving average is applied? I'm printing `model.trainable_variables[0][0,0,0,0]` and it doesn't seem to be impacted by that operation… Is there something I miss?

Comment: BTW, the optimiser is not set in my model. Does that make any difference (I'm updating my question to reflect this)

Comment: I'll edit out the `model.optimizer` it changes nothing here. As I stated in the answer, the EMA object only holds and updates the values of shadow variables of your model. What to do with those shadow variables is up to you. You might want to load them in your model at inference time for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me better understand how this works. I updated the question to ask specifically how the shadow variables should be loaded, I think it makes the question more complete. Do you mind answering that last part? Many thanks again.

Comment: I added a small snippet. I hope it'll help you understand how to use the EMA in your applications.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. In the documentation, it says that `ema` returns an `op`. Isn't it necessary to call that op?

Comment: Only in certain cases. It returns a [`tf.group` op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) that have the following note:"Note: *In TensorFlow 2 with eager and/or Autograph, you should not require  this method, as code executes in your expected order.* Only use tf.group when  working with v1-style code or in a graph context such as inside `Dataset.map`."

Answer (score 3):

### EMA with customizing `model.fit`

Here is a working example of **Exponential Moving Average** with customizing the `fit`. [Ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage).

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf 

class EMACustomModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.999)

    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        opt_op = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        '''About: tf.control_dependencies: 
        Note: In TensorFlow 2 with eager and/or Autograph, you should not 
        require this method, as code executes in the expected order. Only use 
        tf.control_dependencies when working with v1-style code or in a graph 
        context such as inside Dataset.map.
        '''
        with tf.control_dependencies([opt_op]):
            self.ema.apply(self.trainable_variables)

        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

**DummyModel**

```
import numpy as np

input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(flat)

model = EMACustomModel(input, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae"])
```

**DummyData**

```
np.random.seed(101)
x = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(50, 28, 28)).astype("float32")
y = np.random.random((50, 1))
print(x.shape, y.shape)

# train the model 
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

```
...
...
Epoch 49/50
2/2 - 0s - loss: 189.8506 - mae: 10.8830
Epoch 50/50
2/2 - 0s - loss: 170.3690 - mae: 10.1046

model.trainable_weights[:1][:1]
```